# dependency could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to build a web site using .net framework core with entity framework core.  I created a web project using the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.net core) template with Visual Studio 2015 Professional (update 3).  Then I used Nuget to add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to the solution.

When I compiled the solution, I got this dependency error - "NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools >= 1.0.0-preview2-final could not be resolved".  I googled the topic but couldn't find the solution.  How can I fix this??

Comment: Did you install asp.net core? Check if your package is compatible with your current asp.net core version.

Comment: i have .net core 1.01 - vs 2015 tooling preview 2 installed.  I did a repair but still have the dependency not resolved issue.

Comment: Update your question with your `project.json`.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",

Comment: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"

Answer (score 9):

For those who may run into this problem, you would need to right click on the References and click Restore Packages.  That solved the problem.

Comment: It does resolve the problem, but it seems the classes still cannot be referenced in the project.  VS attempts to locate them in the .net core rather than .net 452

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following nuget Packages sources in your nuget package?

https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json

You can do so in Tools > Nuget Package Manager Settings > Packages sources

Also, what is your SDK version?

It should be "1.0.0-preview2-003131".

Comment: what does the index.json do?  The .net core SDK version is 1.01 - VS2015 tooling preview 2 from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows.  Was anybody able to set up a .net core web app with entity frameowork core?  If so, would you share the dependencies section of the project.json?

Comment: I allows you to restore dependencies that are in beta, I have the same message as you when I was trying to restore SignalR packages because they were in that package source, not the release one.